# Index a list of integers using Solr (Sunspot)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

Is there a way of indexing a list of integers using Sunspot and Rails?

**Example**

I want to be able to search for an actor id.
*The code below is just pseudo code.*

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    integers :actors_lists do
      actors.map(&:id)
    end
  end
end
```

I **don't** need the ability to search for actors name, I just to be able to search for actors ids.

I'm using Rails 3.1 RC with Sunspot 1.2.1 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: It seems to me that you already have the solution. Your pseudo code is actually the code you need (assuming the fact that you have an actor_lists in your model). Can you provide more details on what is not working? Is the search method that you don't know how to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
integer :actors_lists, multiple: true do
  actors.map(&:id)
end
```

Adding the `multiple: true` part solved the problem.

*Note: If you're using Ruby 1.8.7, remember to change `multiple: true` to `:multiple => true`.*

Answer (score 0):

If a Movie has_and_belongs_to_many :actors then

```
integer :actor_ids, multiple => true
```

should work. Search parameter named differently from what you wanted, but this one is a "Convention over configuration" case, and here you can use

```
:references => ::Actor
```

Just thought I should mention all options.